# Remove a row from a powershell array/collection/hashtable

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a large array (imported from an Excel spreadsheet) that has a "total" row that I want to delete. It is always the last item in the array. I've tried to find a way to just delete the last array item, but can't. Data and code sample below:

```
$data = Import-XLSX -Path "C:\Pathtofile\spreadsheet.xlsx" -Sheet "SheetName" -RowStart 3
$data | ? {$_.Server -eq "Total"}


Server        : Total
VLAN          :
IP Address    :
CPU           : 84
RAM           : 313
C:\           : 2840
D:\           : 17950
OS Version    :
OS Edition    :
SQL Version   :
SQL Edition   :
Datastore     :
Reboot        :
Notes         :
```

I'd like to be able to delete this row from the array. I've tried the following:

```
$data.Remove("Total")
Exception calling "Remove" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
At line:1 char:1
+ $ImportCSV.Remove("Total")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

If I check the array type, I get the following:

```
$data.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

If I retype the object like so, I get the following:

```
$data = {$data}.Invoke()
$data.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Collection`1                             System.Object

$data.Remove("Total")
False
```

This does not delete the item. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Arrays are immutable in PowerShell, you can't add or remove elements from them. What you can do is:

a) Make a new array and filter *out* the one you don't want (e.g. with `-ne`):

```
$data = $data | ? {$_.Server -ne "Total"}
```

or

b) Select everything up to the last element by index (might be resource hungry on a big array, I don't know):

```
$data = $data[0..($data.Count-2)]
```

or

c) Cast it to `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`, which is mutable, then remove an element from it:

```
$data = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$data
$data.RemoveAt($data.Count-1)
```

Comment: I tried method one and method three with success! Note that with the "immutable" nature of the array, I am able to trim "blank" rows with the following command: $data | Where-Object { ($_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { $_.Value }) -ne $null }. This is why I thought I could simply remove the last entry.

Comment: @McKenning: Your `$data | Where-Object ...` command creates a _new_ array, as any pipeline that outputs more than 1 object does. Even if you assign the result back to the same variable, it is still a new array, as this example demonstrates: `$a = 1, 2, 3; $aToo = $a; $a = $a | ? { $_ -ne 2 }; 'new $a:'; $a; 'original $a:'; $aToo`.

Answer (score 10):

To complement [TessellatingHeckler's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40274662/45375) with analysis and background information:

- As stated, **PowerShell arrays (.NET type `[System.Object[]]`) are *fixed-size* - you cannot add or remove elements** (you can, however, change the *value* of *existing elements*).

  - When you "add" elements to a PowerShell array with `+` or `+=`, a *new* array is created behind the scenes, which is a *copy* (shallow clone) of the original.
  - The only **reason arrays have `.Add()`, `.Remove()`, and `.RemoveAt()` methods** is that they implement the **general-purpose `System.Collections.IList` interface**, which is implemented by many different types of collections, some of which *are* resizable.
    Attempting to call these methods on a fixed-size collection such as an array results in the `"Collection was of a fixed size."` error message you saw.
- **Sending *anything* through the pipeline that outputs more than 1 object comes out as a (new) *array***, irrespective of the type of the input collection. (A single result object is output as itself, not wrapped in a collection.)

  - Therefore, filtering out elements of a collection with commands such as `$data | ? {$_.Server -ne "Total"}` creates a *new* collection that is always an *array* (`[System.Object[]]`, if there's more than 1 output object).

---

**Why your attempts failed**:

`$data.Remove("Total")` failed *fundamentally*, because arrays do not support removal, as mentioned.

But even if `$data` *were* a resizable collection (such as `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`), passing `"Total"` wouldn't have worked, because **the [`IList.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) method you tried to call requires that you pass the element to remove *itself***, which in your case would be the *object* whose `.Server` property contains `"Total"`, most easily accessed as `$data[-1]`.

Also note that passing a value that isn't an element of the list is a *quiet* no-op (if the collection is resizable).

Given that you wanted to remove the *last* element, the index-based [`IList.RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx) method would have been the simpler choice, however.

---

**`{$data}.Invoke()` indeed performs a *retyping* of sorts, but in an arcane fashion that is best avoided**:

At first glance, *conceptually*, that command should be a *no-op*: you're simply enclosing a variable reference in a *script block* (`{ ... }`), which you then invoke, which should simply outputs the variable's *value*.

The reason it *isn't* a no-op is that **you're bypassing PowerShell's normal handling of script blocks by invoke it via the .NET `.Invoke()` method** instead of how script blocks are normally called: with call operator `&`.

If you use `.Invoke()` on a script block, you *always* get a `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]` instance (even if it contains only 1 object).

By contrast, using `&` does additional work after invoking `.Invoke()` behind the scenes: if the collection contains just 1 element, that element is returned directly (the collection is unwrapped). Otherwise, the collection is converted to a PowerShell array (`[System.Object[]]`; I'm unclear on the specifics of this conversion).

Since you used `.Invoke()` directly, your call to `.Remove()` operated on `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`, which *is* resizable, 
and has its own `.Remove()` method whose removal logic is the same as that of `IList.Remove()`, which it shadows.

However, it differs from `IList.Remove()` in that returns a `[bool]` reflecting success of the removal attempt, which is why you got a `false` on your 2nd attempt.

Unlike in the 1st attempt, however, this time the failure wasn't fundamental, and passing in the *object* (row) that the last element contained would have worked; similarly, `.RemoveAt()` with the highest index would have worked:

```
# Convert to [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]
$dataResizable = { $data }.Invoke()

# Remove last item by index.
$dataResizable.RemoveAt($dataResizable.Count-1)

# Alternative: Remove last item by object reference / value.
# Returns [bool], which we suppress.
$null = $dataResizable.Remove($dataResizable[-1])
```

---

All that said, **using `.Invoke()` on a script block just to get a resizable collection is ill-advised**.
Instead, choose one of the methods demonstrated in [TessellatingHeckler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40274662/45375).

Additionally, **PSv5+** offers a simple way to remove the last element from a collection passed through a pipeline, `Select-Object -SkipLast 1`:

```
$data = Import-XLSX -Path "C:\Pathtofile\spreadsheet.xlsx" -Sheet "SheetName" -RowStart 3 |
  Select-Object -SkipLast 1
```